# Python pandas script throwing error in python 3.8

Tags: python, pandas

Below code is working fine in python version 3.6.6 but when python upgraded to 3.8.1 I am getting error

```
num = Data["Description"].size
```

Below error I am getting in Python 3.8.1 version

```
"Elogmsg" : "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py\", 
line 2897, in get_loc\n    return self._engine.get_loc(key)\n  File \"pandas/_libs/index.pyx\", 
line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc\n  File \"pandas/_libs/index.pyx\", 
line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc\n  File \"pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi\", 
line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item\n  File \"pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi\", 
line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item\nKeyError: 'Description'\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, 
another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/www/Python/Project/march.py\", 
line 161, in main\n    num = Data["Description"].size\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py\", 
line 2995, in __getitem__\n    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py\", 
line 2899, in get_loc\n    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))\n  File \"pandas/_libs/index.pyx\", 
line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc\n  File \"pandas/_libs/index.pyx\", 
line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc\n  File \"pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi\", 
line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item\n  File \"pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi\", 
line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item\nKeyError: 'Description'\n",
```

Can anyone help me why code is not working in 3.8.1 python version

Comment: please tell us which pandas version you are using.

Comment: `KeyError: 'Description'` - Are you sure that's the name of the column?

Comment: @Tgsmith61591, Yes same script works under 3.6.6 version Pandas version I am using is 0.25.3

Comment: What's the output of `Data.columns`?

Comment: We're missing some information here. For one, you haven't shared the output of `df.columns`. There's also no way to reproduce this.